# How can I obtain key of a datastore Entity

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've take a Datastore Entity like below.

```
$query = $Datastore->query()
           ->kind('Test')
           ->filter('User', '=', $_POST['txtMail'])
           ->filter('Password', '=', $_POST['txtPwd']);

$result = $Datastore->runQuery($query);
```

I'd like take the Key/Keys of the Entity/Entitys in $result, but if I do:

```
$Entity->key();
```

was returned 0 (zero Entity in $result) and 1,2,3,... if I have one or more Entity.
My Datastore entity was like:

```
ID/Name           |       User       |         Password
Numeric AutoGen.  |  String          | String
```

What I want do is something like this:

```
$query = $Datastore->query()
           ->kind('Test')
           ->filter('User', '=', $_POST['txtMail'])
           ->filter('Password', '=', $_POST['txtPwd']);

$result = $Datastore->runQuery($query);
foreach ($result as $entity){
  /*how to get entity key from here*/
}
```

Comment: The `->key()` method is the right one, see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-datastore/blob/master/Entity.php#L158. Something else is going on.

Comment: Ok, but why if I do a Query like "SELECT * FROM X where User = 'Test@test.com' AND Password = 'xxxxxxxx'" I expect the key value was 5659118702428160 but if I print out the Entity->Key() value is 1?

Comment: Keys are not plain values, they're lists of pairs of key kinds and key IDs. Key IDs may be integers like the ones you mention. I don't know PHP, so I can't tell what exactly are you printing or why does it look like that. Check https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#levels_of_parents, those are keys. Not plain integers

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks for the reply but the link u indicated me seems the methodology for operate with ''foreign key''

Comment: Not really - that kind of objects is what `->key()` returns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Google said ‘If you want to display the entity IDs to the user, and/or depend upon their order, the best thing to do is use manual allocation.’ I’ve use custom IDs for my entity and working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way, Google Datastore provides the key object with a function `pathEndIdentifier`, you can use it like this:

```
echo $entity->key()->pathEndIdentifier();
```

Here is a better example using your previous code:

```
$query = $Datastore->query()
       ->kind('Test')
       ->filter('User', '=', $_POST['txtMail'])
       ->filter('Password', '=', $_POST['txtPwd']);

$result = $Datastore->runQuery($query);
foreach ($result as $entity){
    // get the entity id using pathEndIdentifier()
    echo $entity->key()->pathEndIdentifier();
}
```

You can find here several examples using the PHP wrapper for the google datastore:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/blob/master/2-structured-data/src/DataModel/Datastore.php